# Как анимировать точки SVG полигона?

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, css-animation

Я создал линейную диаграмму с SVG (точками полигона), которые я хотел бы анимировать.

Мне нужно, чтобы все точки начали анимацию вверх от оси X, и когда анимация закончится, результат  выглядел бы следующим образом, как на рисунке ниже.

Кажется, что нет простого способа найти это решения с помощью поиска в Google, который я сделал. Любые советы будут наиболее ценными, спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to animate SVG polygon points?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43090894/7394871) от участника  [@Keith Donegan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/37418/keith-donegan).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43090894/how-to-animate-svg-polygon-points/43097281#43097281

Comment: Я выбрал эту статью, потому что она, несмотря на кажущуюся простоту, открывает ряд весьма интересных возможностей.
Представьте, что можно реализовать, а потом анимировать любую фигуру, задавая только местоположение точек и их перемещение относительно друг друга. Например дизайн шапки сайта https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/  месяца два назад был сделан точно также Сейчас Крис Койер выбрал другой дизайн, но он всё время меняет его.

Comment: Иные технические решения, только приветствуются :) Очень интересен был бы вариант анимации на CSS. И совсем не обязательно воспроизводить эту же форму точь в точь. Но и совсем простых примитивов тоже не хотелось бы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Также не стоит забывать, что свойство `clip-path` можно анимировать.

UPD: + SVG-fallback для фаерфокса, однако в этом браузере анимации не будет.

```css
.graph {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #000 20%, #666 20%, #666 40%, #bbb 40%, #bbb 60%, #ccc 60%, #ccc 80%, #eee 80%);
  height: 200px;
  animation: graph 2s forwards;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 20% 100%, 40% 100%, 60% 100%, 80% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 80% 100%, 60% 100%, 40% 100%, 20% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: url('#clip-start');
  clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 20% 100%, 40% 100%, 60% 100%, 80% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 80% 100%, 60% 100%, 40% 100%, 20% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

@keyframes graph {
  to {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 90%, 20% 80%, 40% 50%, 60% 30%, 80% 60%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 80% 100%, 60% 100%, 40% 100%, 20% 100%, 0% 100%);
    clip-path: url('#clip-finish');
    clip-path: polygon(0% 90%, 20% 80%, 40% 50%, 60% 30%, 80% 60%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 80% 100%, 60% 100%, 40% 100%, 20% 100%, 0% 100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class=graph></div>

<svg>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip-start" clipPathunits="objectBoundingBox">
      <polygon points="0,1 .2,1 .4,1 .6,1 .8,1 1,1 1,1 .8,1 .6,1 .4,1 .2,1 0,1" />
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id="clip-finish" clipPathunits="objectBoundingBox">
      <polygon points="0,.9 .2,.8 .4,.5 .6,.3 .8,.6 1,0 1,1 .8,1 .6,1 .4,1 .2,1 0,1" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: @Очень даже интересно выглядит. + за творческий подход! Прямо стесняюсь спросить .. про FF - забыл?

Comment: Не забыл, просто лень было писать свг-фоллбек )

Answer (score 9):

Что вы подразумеваете под «анимацией с оси X»? Вы имеете в виду, что начинаете строить диаграмму и анимировать её до  формы, как на рисунке?

Если это так, то на самом деле это очень легко.

```html
<svg  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 2040 352">
  <defs>
  </defs>
  
  <polygon points="" fill="red">
     <animate attributeName="points" dur="6s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="4"
             values = "0,352, 550,352, 1240,352, 1592,352, 1880,352, 2040,352,
                   2040,352,0,352; 0,292, 550,232, 1240,258, 1592,158, 1880,168, 2040,0,
                   2040,352,0,352;0,352, 550,352, 1240,352, 1592,352, 1880,352, 2040,352,
                   2040,352,0,352 " />           
    
  </polygon>
</svg>
```

В этом примере используются простые анимации `SVG SMIL`. Вы также можете использовать одну из нескольких графических или анимационных библиотек `SVG`.

**Примечание переводчика**

Вся соль анимации заключается в одной строчке, вернее даже в значении
   `values =" a1,b1; a2,b2; a1,b1" ,где

 a1,b1` - координаты парами всех точек ломанной линии в первом положении.

Через точку с запятой идут координаты точек в финальном положении **a2,b2** и снова через точку с запятой координаты точек в начальном положении.
 Таким образом анимация плавно перемещает ломанную линию от старта до финиша и обратно.

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [How to animate SVG polygon points?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43097281/7394871) от участника  [@Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Такой эффект достижим с `transform:scaley`:

(JS тут только для формирования случайной картинки, анимация - css)

```js
let n = 5, w = innerWidth - 20, h = innerHeight - 20;
let pts = Array(n).fill(0).map((_, i) => [(1+i)*(w/(n+1)), -Math.random()* h]);

document.body.innerHTML += `<svg width=${w} height=${h} viewbox=0,${-h},${w},${h} >
  <polygon points=0,0,${pts},${w},0 /></svg>`;
```

```css
@keyframes grow {
  0%   {transform: scaley(0)}
  100% {transform: scaley(1)}
}

polygon {
  fill: #e45;
  animation: grow 0.5s forwards;
}
```

Comment: Отлично. Полезный и интересный ответ